# Convert from mpf to Sympy Float without losing precision

Tags: python, sympy, mpmath

Is there any way to do this? For example in the code below I lose precision:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.mpmath import *
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> a = mpf('1.0')/mpf('3.0')
>>> a
mpf('0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333311')
>>> b = Float(a,50)
>>> b
0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633
```

Comment: What SymPy version are you on? When I run the same test, I see no precision loss.

Comment: I tested on 0.7.2, but it looks like it should also work on 0.7.6. Are you sure you had the precision set right for all operations? Try testing it again, with the operations in the exact order they appear in your question.

Comment: I tried again with same result. What you see above is a copy-paste.

Answer (score 3):

Converting to a string first seems to do the trick:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.mpmath import *
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> a = mpf('1.0')/mpf('3.0')
>>> a
mpf('0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333311')
>>> b = Float(a,50)
>>> b
0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633
>>> b = Float(str(a),50)
>>> b
0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

Answer (score 2):

`sympify(a)` does the right thing. `Float(a)` ought to work too, but it seems [there is a bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11092).

Comment: I believe that sympify lost precision as well.

Comment: Make sure you are using SymPy 1.0. It looks like this has been fixed in that release.